# "IndexError: tuple index out of range" when using pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Using -python 3.10

-pyinstaller-5.0.dev0
When I attempt to run pyinstaller this occurs:

```
C:\Users\Tyler\pythonscripts>pyinstaller scifair.py
242 INFO: PyInstaller: 5.0.dev0
242 INFO: Python: 3.10.0
254 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.19044-SP0
254 INFO: wrote C:\Users\Tyler\pythonscripts\scifair.spec
256 INFO: UPX is not available.
258 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\Tyler\\pythonscripts']
543 INFO: checking Analysis
543 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
543 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
545 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
558 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
3695 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook distutils from 'C:\\Users\\Tyler\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_find_module_path\\hook-distutils.py'.
3696 INFO: distutils: retargeting to non-venv dir 'C:\\Users\\Tyler\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib'
4636 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
4786 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
4789 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by C:\Users\Tyler\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe
4838 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\Tyler\pythonscripts\scifair.py
5492 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook site from 
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

This error occurs with every project that I have attempted to convert to into an executable file.
Thanks for any answers!